# problem with game that I am creating python

Tags: python, function

I was Creating this game , it is simply hangman is game which is the program choose a word randomly from a list  , and the user guess a letter from the randomly chosen word , if the word is incorrect the lives count decrease until its depleted .

```
import random as rn
words = ['peter','apple','dentist']

stages = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''']

chosen_word = rn.choice(words)
print(chosen_word)

blanks = []
lives = 6
state = False
for j in range(0 , len(chosen_word)):
  blanks += '_'




while not state  :
  guess = input('Enter a letter : ')

  guess.lower()


  for position in range(len(chosen_word)) :
    letter = chosen_word[position]
    if letter == guess :
      blanks[position] = letter 
  print(blanks)   

  if '_' not in blanks :
    state = True
    print('Youy Won !')

  if guess not in letter :
    lives -= 1
    print(stages[lives])
    if lives == 0 :
      state = True
      print('You Lose !')
```

My problem is why it keeps printing the stages list even if the letter chosen is true ?

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`. It helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: you have to assign `guess = guess.lower()`

Comment: you use `len(chosen_word)` many times but it never change - so you could assign to variable and use variable.

Comment: simpler and without `len(chosen_word)` you can do: `for letter in chosen_word: ...`

Comment: this makes no sense `if guess not in letter:` and this is your problem. It should be `if guess not in chosen_word:`

Comment: i have already included  guess.lower() , moreover , if i put for letter in chosen_word , it is not going to work ,as it is string , and you will have the message : 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: it should make sense , because  i have assigned it to the variable letter :     letter = chosen_word[position]

Comment: but you run it in loop which change `letter` in every loop - so finally you have last letter, not letter which match to guess. You would have to exit (`break`) loop when you find matching `letter`

Comment: yep it should change the letter , because it looping over the letters of chosen_word , look the variable letter will be equal thet letter which correspond to index  determined by :  letter = chosen_word[position]   , so position is already looping over the letters of chosen_word then if it true the the '_' which is in the list called blanks , will be replaced by the letter if it's correct , or the count will decrese -1 ,  actually , if we get rid of the print statement of stages in the end of the code ,  the game will work correctly .   i have tried your suggestion but it did not work either .

Comment: my full code in answer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `if guess not in letter:`. You check in `guess` in wrong element.

It has to be `if guess not in chosen_word:`

That's all.

---

OR you should exit (`break`) loop when you found matching `letter` - but you run loop to the end - so you assign new values to `letter` and finally it has last letter from `chosen_word` which doesn't match to `guess`.

But this would replace only first `letter` matching to `guess` and skip other - ie. in `apple` if you choose `p` it would match only first `p` and skip second `p` - so first version is better.

```
    for position, letter in enumerate(chosen_word):
        if letter == guess :
            blanks[position] = letter
            break  # <--- exit loop when found letter
```

If you use `print()` to see what you have in variables then you should see mistake.

---

You have also wrong indentations.

Full working code with some small changes.

```
import random

stages = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''']

words = ['peter','apple','dentist']

chosen_word = random.choice(words)
print(chosen_word)

blanks = ['_'] * len(chosen_word)
lives = 6
state = False

while not state  :
    guess = input('Enter a letter : ')

    guess = guess.lower()

    for position, letter in enumerate(chosen_word):
        if letter == guess :
            blanks[position] = letter
      
    print(blanks)   

    if '_' not in blanks:
        state = True
        print('Youy Won !')

    if guess not in chosen_word:
        lives -= 1
        
    print(stages[lives])
    
    if lives == 0:
        state = True
        print('You Lose !')
```